# Terracotta - What is saved in server-data directory?

Tags: ehcache, terracotta

We use terracotta 3.6 and configure the persistence-mode as "temporary-swap-only".

But our "server-data" directory grow a lot with binary files, the configuration reference from terracotta said: 
*"This element specifies the path where the server should store its data for persistence." (http://terracotta.org/documentation/4.0/terracotta-server-array/config-reference#tctc-configserversserverdata)*

- What else store terracotta in the "server-data" directory?
- How can we avoid that terracotta store binary files in "server-data" directory?

Answer (score 0):

Server-data will also contain data files in case if their is any overflow of data from heap due to heap pressure. Please check your logs for heap pressure or use BigMemory [Will have to use 4.x version for freemium version].

Cheers,
Ridhav